# Lack of Heroku PHP GD setup for JPEG files causing issues

Tags: php, heroku, facebook-apps

Heroku does not support GD setup for jpg. Because of this I am not able to create collage out of profile pics, which are only in jpg format. I am having the same issue as the below link.

http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/browse_thread/thread/5f0b169272dd075f/5926d2e6eace859c?utoken=sizyOCkAAAD0zGxoh6dI3732ocaO_CKc0UdN2a4MLXn0dn7f9oF9dw34Femrnx-0ZHcOkI9yXY0

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: ImageMagick. I am not able to find info about heroku support for that

Comment: [On the cedar platform you can compile your own PHP extensions](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/php-on-heroku-again/).

Answer (score 1):

My alternative was to use `imagick.so` extension instead. See my reply @stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573916/how-can-i-add-jpeg-support-to-heroku-php-buildpack) for instruction how to get this extension up and running quickly. Let me know if this works (the few basic functions I tried are ok).

The official buildpack from Heroku doesn't list PHP. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does support ImageMagick.  I ran in to the GD/JPG problem hosting a WordPress site, but it was easily fixed by installing the imagemagick-engine plugin.  Using it from the command line works with the path /usr/bin .  The PHP module is not installed.