# How can I add jpeg support to Heroku PHP buildpack

Tags: php, heroku, gd, php-ini

I am developping an app using Heroku. I will need to manipulate images but unfortunately `jpeg` is not supported by default. I spoke with support and here is their answer:

```
"We unfortunately don't support jpeg by default. But the good
news is that we open sourced our PHP buildpack, so hopefully the
community will be able to bring that in.

In case you're interested, the buildpack is here:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php"
```

I know I need to add `--with-jpeg` just before the `--with-gd` in the `./configure` of PHP

But the buildpack only gives the ability to update the *php.ini* and *compile* files and none of them contains the magic line to update (./configure...) ...

Is there is a way to add `jpeg` support through the two mentioned files ?

Comment: Now that PHP support on Heroku is official and there is an official and well-maintained buildpack, you can just include ImageMagick in your [composer.json](https://github.com/delight-im/Heroku-PHP-Apache2/blob/master/composer.json) file as `ext-imagick`, or use `ext-gd`.

Answer (score 3):

Current workaround is to install `imagick.so` - have compiled the library and instruction @ [github](https://github.com/alkhoo/heroku-cedar-php-extension) `https://github.com/alkhoo/heroku-cedar-php-extension`

Also compiled `apc.so` since it is missing from Heroku's extension. The `gd.so` extension cannot be used since Heroku's PHP had GD compiled in php* binary. Waiting for someone to create a PHP buildpack without GD compiled.

Others have compiled `zlib.so` and `mbstring.so` (in case anyone is interested).