# jpeg not supported by GD, any other way to convert jpeg images

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, heroku, gd

Hello I am working over a Facebook app that’s requires retrieving users display picture and merge it with another image, the problem is I am using `heroku` which does not provide GD support for jpeg images, hence I can’t work it out while the image format is jpeg.

- I need suggestions to work out this problem of mine somehow.
- Is it possible that i include support for jpeg by including some library in
  my project and referencing in my code.

This is what I am getting while the input image is jpeg:

`Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in …`
`Warning: imagegif() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in…`

```
$dpImageGif = 'temp/'. $userId '.gif';
        $url = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/{$userId}/picture?type=large");
$dpImage = 'temp/' . $userId ;
$imageObject = imagecreatefromstring($url);
//$imageObject = imagecreatefromjpeg($dpImage);
imagegif($imageObject, $dpImageGif);
```

`gd_info():`

```
array(11) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(27) "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["T1Lib Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: ehh what kind of php build would not support jpeg...? Have you tried seeing what is even contained within $url?

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627701/lack-of-heroku-php-gd-setup-for-jpeg-files-causing-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Heroku does support ImageMagick on PHP, which you can use instead of GD for JPEG image processing. Not very useful for existing apps, but if you're starting from scratch it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You can compile the GD extension your own and use it instead on heroku.

Comment: Also the Heroku PHP build pack is open source, so I've been trying to figure out how to add GD with ImageJPEG directly to the build pack. No luck yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled my own `imagick.so` as a workaround, see my reply @stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573916/how-can-i-add-jpeg-support-to-heroku-php-buildpack). Let me know if it works (the basic functions I've tried works).